# Runtime Error 91 : Export Global contact list in outlook 2016

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Now I'm export Global contact list in outlook 2016. to Excel file. This's my code:

```
 Sub ExportOutlookAddressBook()
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
 Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace
 Dim olAL As Outlook.AddressList
 Dim olEntry As Outlook.AddressEntry

 Set olApp = Outlook.Application
 Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set olAL = olNS.AddressLists("Global Address List") 'Change name if different contacts list name
 ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
 For Each olEntry In olAL.AddressEntries
 'ActiveCell.Value = olEntry.GetContact.FullName 
 ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Value = olEntry.Name
 ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
 Next olEntry
 Set olApp = Nothing
 Set olNS = Nothing
 Set olAL = Nothing
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

It have Runtime Error 91!.How can I Fix this Error? >/\<

[image: This's my Global contact list.]

[image: This's my result]

Comment: I do not have a global address list so I changed the address list to "Contacts".  Your code worked perfectly for me.  Where and how is the error reported?

Comment: Which line causes the error? Keep in mind that larger GAL containers woudl raise an exception if you try to loop through all entries. How many entries get processed before you run into a problem?

Comment: Dear Tony Dallinor, Dmitry Streblechenko.
Apologize for not clear question.
I have global contact list. But when i run my code.I retrive only "name". ><

Comment: According to your images, you have successfully extracted at least 14 names from the GAL and saved them in an Excel worksheet.  Is this a correct interpretation of your images?  Did you get error 91 before all names have been extracted or after all names have been extracted?  If the code failed before the extraction finished, how did the entry that resulted in failure differ from the preceding entries?

Answer (score 0):

Use ***GetExchangeUser*** istead of ***GetContact***.

For example:

```
    Dim olExUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser

    Set olExUser = Nothing
    Set olExUser = olEntry.GetExchangeUser
    If Not olExUser Is Nothing Then
        With olExUser
            ActiveCell.Value = .FirstName & " " & .LastName
        End With
    End If
```